# How to define the html value attribute in a ul/li menu?

Tags: html

I have a menu that isn't marked with the attribute (select - option) but is marked with `ul li` tag:

```
<select>
<option value="18">18</option>
</select>
```

How can I define a value like the menu marked with tag (select - option) in a menu marked with tag `ul li`

The menu marked with `ul li` is an "AGE SELECT" menu so I want to put values that range from 18 to 50.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text` attribute in `li` tag.
It is equals to `value` attribute in `option` tag.

Comment: like this :     <ul><li text="1">1</li></ul>    ??